# cannot read property'length' of undefined

Tags: d3.js, undefined

I made a graph but it doesnt look right I went to my console and saw no errors. I run a single piece of the code, `line().x(function(i){return x(i);})` and `line().y(function(d){return y(d);})` getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` both times

update running line() gives me the same error

```
var data = [3, 6, 2, 7, 5, 2, 0, 3, 8, 9, 2, 5, 9, 3, 6, 3, 6, 2, 7, 5, 2, 1, 3, 8, 9, 2, 5, 9, 2, 7,15];
var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0,data.length]).range([0,wid]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0,10]).range([height,0]);
var line=d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(i){return x(i);})
    .y(function(d){return y(d);})
```

Comment: How are you passing `data` to `line`?

Comment: I don't understand why you are returning `x(i)` and `y(d)` ? `x` and `y` are no functions here. Can you show us more code ?

Comment: right now im not, but i dont have to, x and y have data in them.

Comment: Maybe, but with parenthesis you are calling a function, not accessing data. `x` and `y` are arrays or objects ? I don't know what returns `range()`

Comment: it is a thing of d3 i represents index position and d shows index value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing is that `d3.svg.line()` doesn't actually create a line itself.
It creates a path generator that will take some data and turn it into an svg path.

You need to bind the `data` array to an svg path and then set the `"d"` attribute of the path.
It'd look something like this:

```
svg_path_element.data(data).attr("d", line).
```

Your path generator is also defined incorrectly.
The `d` and `i` arguments to the functions aren't special names, they're defined by position. You want the x value to use the index, but because the anonymous function only has one argument, the `i` there will still be the data bound.
You need to actually give the anonymous function two arguments, even if you don't use one, like `.x(function(d, i) { return x(i) })`.

Comment: the svg_path was unneccessary. i just needed to do the (d,i)